# Trace identity - multivariate normal distribution

Tags: linear-algebra, normal-distribution, multivariate-statistical-analysis

As a part of conducting a likelihood ratio test we've defined $W$. $X$ is a $N_p$-distributed r.v. and $\bar{X}$ is vector of the estimated means.

$$W = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} (X_i - \bar{X})(X_i - \bar{X})^T $$

And I have to proof that the trace of $W$ is:

$$\text{tr}(W) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} X_i^T X_i  + n\text{tr} \bar{X}\bar{X}^T$$

I've tried the following:

$$\text{tr}(W) = \text{tr} \left(\sum_{i = 1}^{n} (X_i - \bar{X})  (X_i - \bar{X})^T \right)$$
$$\text{tr}(W) =  \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \text{tr} ((X_i - \bar{X})^T  (X_i - \bar{X}))$$
$$\text{tr}(W) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \text{tr}( (X_i^T - \bar{X}^T)  (X_i - \bar{X}))$$
$$\text{tr}(W) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}  \text{tr}(X_i^TX_i -X_i^T\bar{X} - \bar{X}^TX_i + \bar{X}^T\bar{X} )$$
$$\text{tr}(W) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \text{tr}( X_i^TX_i -X_i^T\bar{X} - \bar{X}^TX_i + \bar{X}^T\bar{X} )$$
$$\text{tr}(W) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}  (X_i^TX_i - X_i^T\bar{X} - \bar{X}^TX_i) + n \text{tr} \bar{X}^T\bar{X} $$

But I can't figure out how to get the $X_i^T\bar{X} - \bar{X}^TX_i$ to "disappear". Any help is appreciated!

Comment: First write down what $X_i$ is.  I would have assumed a 'scalar' normal random variable, but you are using transpose so evidently not.  If the $X_i$ are iid random vectors then what is $\bar{X}$ -- *"vector of the estimated means"* -- estimated means of what? Something more typical would be, if the $X_i$ are random vectors, then $\bar{X}_i:= E\big[X_i\big]$ but that doesn't appear to be the case based on what is written.  Second write out the $n=1$ case.

Comment: Are you sure the result is correct? Because $W = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} X_i X_i^T -n\bar{X}\bar{X}^T$.